# Laravel sail up fail on Linux Mint 20.2

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, linux-mint

I am trying to build a dockerized laravel project following the documentation at *https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-linux*

I ran the following:
`curl -s https://laravel.build/laravel-app | bash` ,
`cd laravel-app`,
`./vendor/bin/sail up`

After pulling tons of files, I believe it comes to bulid the Dockerfile, not sure which as there are 3 Dockerfiles in 3 different folders inside **laravel-app/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes**, there are 3 folders named **7.4, 8.0, and 8.1**, in which each contains a Dockerfile but pretty much the differences are so subtle. These Dockerfiles have 18 commands, so after the pulls are finished it says Step 1/18, 2/18, etc... However it always messes up in step 9, it starts saying "Get: ## http://..ubnutu.com...." where ## is from 1 till 127 and then at the line

`"Get:127 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 gosu amd64 1.12-1build1 [745 kB]"`

it always quits and says:

`E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/libfontconfig1_2.13.1-4.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]`

`E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

My internet connection is stable but it always stops after the 127th Get line.
Also, I ran the command several times and same result happens, so I do not believe it's a connection issue.

Here's the components of the Dockerfile in folder 8.1, it is the 9th step where it is messed up (the second RUN command):

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
       php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
       php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
       php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
       php8.1-ldap \
       php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
       php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

---

Also, I tried to execute the 9th step manually, turns out that probably the problem is in the part of step 9 which says

**"echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf"**, it results in **"bash: /home/${user}/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf: Permission denied"**, I ran it with sudo and chmod u+x but same result.